# C++ Boost.Asio serial port function not firing?

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, boost-asio

I'm not too well versed in boost.asio, but I'm running into an issue with a UART serial port program that I'm setting up where I read asynchronously from the serial port. For the record, I'm running on the latest version of Manjaro Linux. I'll include the code below, but for whatever reason the handler isn't firing (it's called HandlePortOnReceieve). The async_read_some function I realized is indeed firing. Here's what it looks like, and after I'll elaborate on what I think in my humble opinion what "might" be the problem, though I'm not sure how to go about fixing or even testing this to see if my idea is correct.

```
//starts the connection
void SerialHandler::StartConnection(int _baudRate, string _comPort)
{       
    //handle error codes
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    //if ports already open, we don't want to run the code
    if (serialPort)
    {       
            cout <<"Port already open..." << endl;
            return;
    }

    //create serial port at pointer location and open it
    serialPort = serial_port_ptr (new boost::asio::serial_port(ioService));
    serialPort->open(_comPort, ec);

    //prints error if one is incurred
    if (ec) 
    {       
            cout << "error: serialPort->open() failed..." <<endl;
            cout << "Com port name: " << _comPort << "\nerror code: " << ec.message().c_str() <<endl;
    }

    //set serial port properties
    serialPort->set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(_baudRate));
    serialPort->set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::character_size(8));
    serialPort->set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::one));
    serialPort->set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity::none));
    serialPort->set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::none));


    AsyncReadSome();


    boost::thread t1(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioService));

}






void SerialHandler::AsyncReadSome()
{       
    if (serialPort.get()==NULL || !serialPort->is_open())
    {       
            return;
    }

    //calls async read some, passing in the handler that is called (as well as an error code, of course), to be called when the process is finished in ioService (which is acting in another thread for now).
    serialPort->async_read_some (
                    boost::asio::buffer(rawBuffer, SERIAL_PORT_READ_BUF_SIZE),
                    boost::bind(
                            &SerialHandler::HandlePortOnReceive,
                            this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}



void SerialHandler::HandlePortOnReceive(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{

    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);

    cout<<"test"<<endl;

    //if port isnt open at this point or doesn't exist (i.e. if disconnected during running), then we can avoid an error and quit out
    if (serialPort.get()==NULL || !serialPort->is_open())
            return;

    //if there's an error, we'll lose data, but we can always try again as long as program didn't return in the first phase of function
    if (error){
            AsyncReadSome();
            return;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<bytes_transferred; i++)
    {
            char c = rawBuffer[i];
            cout << c << endl;
    }

    //loop back on itself and start the next read
    AsyncReadSome();
}
```

So, in my humble opinion, I believe the issue lies in one of two possible places that I can identify at least. Either the issue is with passing the ioService to another thread to run, which could be causing errors only because I'm under the impression that doing so could open up the program to expansion later on for faster reads. Though, that is only what I read, because that particular line I borrowed from an example I found, so, because I didn't write it, I'm not entirely sure how it factors in.

Second, I think it's possible that the io_service is being run, but there is no work for it to do as it is going faster the AsyncReadSome function that I defined can work, so it runs out of work and returns.

Both those are only working theories though, and I don't know really how to test either seeing as they stem partly from my unfamiliarity with Boost.Asio. I've done a bitof research but can't find anything definitively, so maybe somebody here can offer some insight. Thanks in advance for any input

Comment: For joinable `boost::thread` objects, if their destructor is called, usually, they call `std::terminate`. To avoid this behaviour, you should join the thread, and you didn't join in the given code. Maybe this is the problem? look: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.destructor

Comment: Maybe I've got this wrong, but I purposefully didn't join the thread in an attempt to ensure that it would run continuously, which is why I have the handler calling the AsyncReadSome() function again so that it would loop on itself. I'll try wrapping it in a try-catch block and joining it in the catch block to see if that is indeed what is happening, but according to examples I've seen, being neither joined nor detached shouldn't be bad as long as i join it in a stopreading() function later. But, maybe you're right, becausing calling io_service::run in the main thread works fine.

Comment: The `boost::thread` destructor behavior has changed, so you may have seen examples based on the old behavior. The [current behavior](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.destructor2) is to terminate, same as `std::thread`.

Comment: I think, the best remedy is encapsulating the thread object in a pointer (or a smart pointer) and managing it by `StartConnection` and `EndConnection` (or something). That pointer is initially null, and with `StartConnection`, it stores the thread object, and since it's a pointer, when `StartConnection` goes out the scope the destructor is not called. Deleting the pointer should occur in the class destructor, or `EndConnection` function. I think, this can solve your problem.

Comment: @jnbrq-CanberkSönmez I did try the pointer idea you had and simply created an object 'boost::thread *t1' in my head and said 't1 = new boost::thread(...)' but unfortunately that didn't stop it from exiting at first, but I think my problem was two-fold actually. After that, I realized that my main function was also going out of scope if my thread thread function did not (surprised I didn't catch that earlier). After encapsulating it in a pointer and then adding a simple blocking function into my main, it worked.